# Weighted quartiles with descr() from SummaryTools

Tags: r, summarytools

I`m doing basic descriptive statistics of a household survey dataframe. I have a column who reports the number of times of an event in certain period of time. The survey comes with a `factor` column equivalent to the weight of the observation.

So, when I use this code

```
times_theater<- descr(data17$s08a_02, report.nas = F, stats = "all")
times_theather
```

I  get this

```
Descriptive Statistics  
data17$s08a_02  
N: 38201  

                    s08a_02
----------------- ---------
             Mean      2.58
          Std.Dev      2.41
              Min      1.00
               Q1      1.00
           Median      2.00
               Q3      3.00
              Max     40.00
              MAD      1.48
              IQR      2.00
               CV      0.93
         Skewness      5.80
      SE.Skewness      0.08
         Kurtosis     64.28
          N.Valid   1027.00
        Pct.Valid      2.69
```

This are the "brute" values, so I need to apply the weights:

```
times_theater<- descr(data17$s08a_02, report.nas = F, weights = data17$factor, stats = "all")
times_theather
```

And the output is this:

```
Weighted Descriptive Statistics  
data17$s08a_02  
Weights: factor  
N: 38201  

                    s08a_02
--------------- -----------
           Mean        2.55
        Std.Dev        2.31
            Min        1.00
         Median        2.00
            Max       40.00
        N.Valid   288118.00
      Pct.Valid        2.57
```

As you can see, I lost the quartile's information (Q1, Q3, IQR) and I would really like them to show up in the same output.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

pd: I know in this case the differences are almost non-existent, but there are some spending and income variables I would really need to get the quartiles later on.

Edit2: I know the documentation says descr() quartiles won't work with weights, I want a way to calculate them and insert them in the previous output.

Answer (score 0):

`Hmisc` package contains a bunch of weighted functions including `wtd.quantile`. Consider the following snippet:

```r
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(500)
wts <- sample(1:6, 500, TRUE)
quantile(x)
Hmisc::wtd.quantile(x, wts)
```

Which will result:

```r
> wtd.quantile(x, wts)
         0%         25%         50%         75%        100% 
0.001836858 0.260238785 0.461551841 0.739641746 0.996077372 
> quantile(x)
         0%         25%         50%         75%        100% 
0.001836858 0.258128640 0.476269632 0.734145740 0.996077372
```

As its defaults to quartile values. Of course one can specify any quantile values. Cf. `?wtd.quantile` and there is also `survey::svyquantile`, in case you have a complex sampling design.